# Is there DDL viewer role in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a user that have db_datareader role in SQL Server 2008
I need this user to be able to see Stored Procedures, functions, table scripts, etc.

What role is that? I don't want user to RUN DDL scripts (alter tables or procedures). I just want user to be able to read anything in database.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [**`VIEW DEFINITION`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175808%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

You can grant a principal `VIEW DEFINITION` at various scopes (server, database, schema, specific object).

Example for a stored procedure:

```
Use MyDB
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON p_MyProc TO SomeUser
```

For all objects in a database:

```
Use MyDB
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO SomeUser
```

For all objects on the server:

```
USE master
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO SomeUSer
```

Note: when granting permissions at the server level the principal must also have access at the database level in order to view definitions within the database.